# How can I determine if a date is within a range of dates in C#?

Tags: c#, datetime

I am attempting to write code to perform specific actions if the entered date is between January and April, but I cannot come up with a valid comparison for the two. Using TryParse would not change my string into an appropriate format, and the two types cannot be compared without some form of parsing. This is what I am working with so far:

```
if (dtpCheckIn >= TryParse("1/1/2016") && dtpCheckIn < TryParse("5/1/2016")
{
    //Do Something
}
```

Comment: TryParse returns `true` or `false` values... You need to use `out` keyword to get the actual result of parsing.

Comment: DateTime could be easily compared against another datetime. Just build two datetimes for your test case. IE new DateTime(2016,1,1) and new DateTime(2016,5,1)

Comment: @Steve, actually true. Why parse at all if the dates are predefined, you're right.

Comment: For better understanding look at @Soner's answer below.

Answer (score 2):

```
    var startDate = new DateTime(2016, 1, 1);

    var endDate = new DateTime(2016, 5, 1);   

    var checkInIsValid = dtpCheckIn >= startDate && dtpCheckIn < endDate; 
// i saw that your start, end date are previously defined
```

Answer (score 2):

If you don't have a custom method as `TryParse`, this method belongs on `DateTime` structure and you can use it as [`DateTime.TryParse`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.tryparse). But *even* if you do, this method takes string as a first parameter and takes [`out`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t3c3bfhx.aspx) as a second one (generally using that overload). And it returns `true` or `false` as your string can be parsed or not. It does *not* return a `DateTime`.

I assume your `dtpCheckIn` *already* a `DateTime`, you can easily use `<` and `>=` operators for comparing other `DateTime` instances.

The right syntax can be like;

```
if (dtpCheckIn >= new DateTime(2016, 1, 1) && dtpCheckIn < new DateTime(2016, 5, 1))
{
}
```

Take a look at

- [`DateTime.GreaterThanOrEqual` operator](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.op_greaterthanorequal)
- [`DateTime.LessThan` operator](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.op_lessthan)